# If dentro de while

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy haciendo un sistema de logueo, para validar datos de contraseña correcta, me conecto a la tabla de la base de datos y si la contraseña es correcta me manda a página de *contenido.php*.

Pero no logro hacer funcionar un **if** ya que está dentro de un **while**.

Recojo las variables del formulario:

```
$usuario = $_POST['nnombre'];
$pass = $_POST['npassword'];
```

Ejecutó la sentencia sql:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios_establecidos where usuarios_establecidos = '".$usuario ."'";

$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

Y saco los valores de la tabla:

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

  // output data of each row

  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    if($row['Password'] == $pass){

session_start();

$_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;

header("Location: contenido.php");


}
}

  }else {

  echo "0 results";

}

$conn->close();
```

Comment: Que tal si en el `query` validas le usuario y la contraseña... `SELECT * FROM usuarios_establecidos where usuarios_establecidos = '.$usuario .' AND password = '.$pass .'` de esta manera no tienes que usar ciclos adicionales, solo la primer validación, `if ($result->num_rows > 0) {session_start}`. Recuerda usar consultas preparadas para evitar riesgos de inyección `sql`

Comment: Muchas gracias si me sirvió de mucho su ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Podrías utilizas el `break` al final del `if` [(break)](https://www.php.net/manual/es/control-structures.break.php) u agregar una *bandera booleana* que se actualice en el if y sea parte de la condición del `switch`

Comment: Mostrar el código corregido es más útil y claro que dar simples indicaciones.